# Publish audio via RTMP to Red5 server without flash

Tags: flash, ffmpeg, rtmp, red5, flv

strange problem here so I understand if it's the wrong place to post, would appreciate any help if you can give it.

I have a .swf that records a voice and uploads it to a red5 server via rtmp using Netstream.publish(). I want a way to write a command line tool or bash script for streaming multiple audio files to the same red5 server via rtmp.

I have tried ffmpeg like so, but it doesn't seem to be working
`ffmpeg -i #{file} -f flv #{connection_url}`

**My questions are:**

1) what format must audio be in order to mimic flash's Netstream.publish() ? FLV? If so, I thought flv was a video format?

2) are there any existing tools you would recommend for uploading/streaming the file to the red5 server via rtmp.

3) finally, should i just write my scripts in actionscript using the netstream.publish calls? If that is the case how can I invoke the AS3 in order to batch upload files from the command line?

Thanks and sorry for the obscurity. Any help is appreciated.

Jack

Comment: Are trying to publish a live stream or uploading files to server ?

Comment: The original swf uses the microphone to record a stream and upload it using Netstream.publish(). I want to replicate this function without the swf (if possible) so that I can batch "stream" audio to the server. The server runs some process on the streams that I don't control.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "valid" audio codec and ensure that you're ignoring video, so something like this will work:

```
ffmpeg -i [your file] -vn -acodec libmp3lame -f flv rtmp://[yourhost]/[yourapp]/outputstream
```

The following codecs will work:

- nelly moser
- aac
- speex
- pcm
- mp3

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I want to stream mp3 files to the server, is converting audio to flv the convention here? I se `e the following warnings in my ffmpeg output ```[flv @ 0x7fe64b830000] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x7fe64b830000] Failed to update header with correct filesize.```. Is this anything to be concerned about?

Comment: If you can subscribe to the stream, I wouldn't worry about those